# How do I test expectedExceptionsMessageRegExp (exception message) using TestNG?

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, testng

I'm using the `expectedExceptionsMessageRegExp` propery on the `@Test` annotation to test an exception message, but it is not executing correctly. See the code below.

**Unit test code:**

```
@Test (dependsOnMethods = "test1", expectedExceptions = IllegalArgumentException.class, expectedExceptionsMessageRegExp = "incorrect argument")
public void testConverter()
{
    try
    {
        currencyConverter  = Converter.convert(val1,val2)
    }
    catch (MYException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**Application code:**

```
if (val1 == null || val1.length() == 0)
{
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Val1 is incorrect");
}
```

The unit test code should check the exception message, if the messages are not matching each other, the test should fail.

At present this is not happening. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 5):

It seems to work for me:

> org.testng.TestException: 
>   The exception was thrown with the wrong message: expected "incorrect argument" but got "val1 is incorrect"

Can you post a simple class showing the problem? (either here or on the testng-users mailing-list)